Installing Miniconda within Windows Subsystem Linux
I'm trying to install Qiime 2 on a Windows machine for microbiome data analysis. My understanding is that part of this process involves installing MiniConda within Windows Subsystem for Linux.
When I enter this line wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh in WSL to download MiniConda, I get the following output.
--2024-11-19 10:04:03--  https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
Resolving repo.anaconda.com (repo.anaconda.com)... 104.16.191.158, 104.16.32.241
Connecting to repo.anaconda.com (repo.anaconda.com)|104.16.191.158|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to repo.anaconda.com (repo.anaconda.com)|104.16.32.241|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

...until the connection times out.
My computer is connected to the internet. How can I connect to the Anaconda website in WSL?

Can your WSL system connect to internet? Does sudo apt update work?

Have you confirmed you can reach the internet?  Run ping 8.8.8.8 and nslookup google.com in the WSL environment to make sure you can reach outbound.  Are you on a secure network which requires a proxy or authentication to connect to Internet resources?  Are you in a country that might block these domains and IPs?

Thanks both for your replies. Based on entering these commands, it seems my WSL environment can't reach the internet. I'm in the US and I don't think I'm being blocked from these domains. I'm on a secure network but can use the internet without logging into a VPN if that's what is mean by proxy or authentication?

How can I configure my WSL environment to connect to the internet?

Try the following:
Open a terminal
Run in it
sudo bash -c 'echo -e "[network]
generateResolvConf = false" > /etc/wsl.conf
echo -e "options timeout:1 attempts:1 rotate
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4" > /etc/resolv.conf
chattr -f +i /etc/resolv.conf'

wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh

